# How to step into NuGet packages outside of debug session

Tags: c#, .net, gitlab, nuget, sourcelink

#### Following situation:

We have a framework that sits in an hosted GitLab repository. We have a pipeline that creates a NuGet package `nuget pack framework.sln` which is consumable in any VS solution. So far so good.

Now we want to be able to step into the framework code inside any other solution. E.g. `framework.myClass.myMethod() > Rightclick > "Go to implementation"` but without having to start a debug session. Just while normally editing the code.

#### What I tried so far:

- I tried to create `.snupkg` packages by changing the command to `nuget pack framework.sln -Symbols`
- I tried to use [SourceLink](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink) which I was not able to get up and running

Am I completely wrong on this one? Is it even possible to do so outside a normal debug session? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be impossible in Visual Studio without **Resharper**.

Microsoft has been working on this for a while:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/55834
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/24349

To setup SourceLink, see this answer:
[Source Link with an Azure DevOps Symbol Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54980381/source-link-with-an-azure-devops-symbol-server)